# Angular and Ionic 4 to listen to live data Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2, ionic4

I am trying to update messages in my ionic 4 app in realtime using angularfire2 and firebase realtime database. The code looks like below

On running it throws the exception 
Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

if i remove the word async then it shows up fine but when i post a new message from another instance then the entire data repeats.

html

```
<ion-list lines="full" style="background:transparent">
                    <ion-item  style="padding-top:10px;" *ngFor="let msg of messages | async">
                        <ion-row  style="width:100%;">
                            <ion-col size="3">
                                <ion-row>
                                    <ion-col class="sg-reg-text">{{formatName(msg.name)}}</ion-col>
                                </ion-row>
                                <ion-row>
                                    <ion-col style="padding:0;padding-left:8px" class="sg-tiny-text"><ion-icon name="time" color="light"></ion-icon>&nbsp;now</ion-col>
                                </ion-row>
                            </ion-col>
                            <ion-col style="border-bottom: 1px solid #7e7c8d;padding-bottom: 10px">
                                <ion-row>
                                    <ion-col class="sg-reg-text">{{msg.message}}</ion-col>
                                </ion-row>
                            </ion-col>
                        </ion-row>
                    </ion-item>
              </ion-list>
```

ts

```
messages:Post[]
refresh(){
this.messages = []
this.sgSvc.getMessages().subscribe(
  (rsp:any) => {
                  for(let data of rsp){
                    console.log("hehe:" + JSON.stringify(data))
                    this.messages.push(new Post(data._name, data._message, data._uid))
                  }

                }
)
  }

ngOnInit() {
this.refresh()
}
```

svc.ts

```
private msgList: AngularFireList<Post>
```

getMessages(){

```
this.msgList = this.db.list<Post>('posts')
return this.msgList.snapshotChanges().pipe(
   map(changes => 
    changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }))
   )
  );
  }
```

Comment: It's because `messages` isn't an `Observable<T>`, it's simply an `Array<T>` that you are pushing objects to. You wouldn't need or should use `async` pipe with `messages`.

Comment: if i dont then i get to another problem i mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following using the RxJS `map()` operator to build the array of `Post` objects rather than pushing the items to `messages` each time in `subscribe()`. You receive duplicate data when you remove the `async` pipe with your current code because you are not re-initializing the array to an empty array. Either way you wouldn't use the `async` pipe with an `Array<T>`:

```
messages: Observable<Post[]>;

// ...

this.messages = this.sgSvc.getMessages().pipe(
  map((messages: any) => messages.map(m => new Post(m._name, m._message, m._uid)));
);
```

You can also approach it without the `async` pipe:

```
messages: Post[] = [];

// ...

this.sgSvc.getMessages().subscribe((messages: any) => {
  this.messages = messages.map(m => new Post(m._name, m._message, m._uid));
});
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: This now lands me in another error: Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: Can you confirm that `messages` is being typed as `Observable<Post[]>`? Also can you confirm, maybe with a temporary subscribe that the map operator is generating an array?

Comment: Can you log out what the map operator is generating? Can you confirm it's creating an array for `Post` objects? Or in the HTML just use the `json` pipe instead of `ngFor`, just for troubleshooting.

Comment: sorry how do i even print that? putting a console.log does not work inside map(messages:any) => .  Also plz note that my svc.ts code is still the same

Comment: In your HTML just do `{{messages | async | json}}`, temporarily remove the `ngFor`. You can also use the `tap` RxJS operator inside `pipe()` like `tap(messages => console.log(messages)` after the outer `map()` operator. We just need to see the structure of what `map()` is creating. You can add this is an update to your question so it can be formatted/reviewed better.

Comment: that prints fine,.   [
  {
    "_name": "Vik Kumar",
    "_message": "you rock shreya",
    "_date": 1547063988434,
    "_uid": "6jXG9ZQFghQA0l5M9qOx4UIqNhB2"
  },
  {
    "_name": "Vik Kumar",
    "_message": "This is an awesome app. I am really happy to be able to write you directly here. Excited!!!",
    "_date": 1547063988434,
    "_uid": "6jXG9ZQFghQA0l5M9qOx4UIqNhB2"
  }
]

Comment: Okay, try one last thing. Revert back to the `*ngFor` and on the `ion-list` try putting an `*ngIf="messages"`.

Comment: :( no luck with that

Comment: Do you have `messages` being used anywhere else in your component template? Do you have any additional `*ngFor` in your template?

Comment: nope i can confirm that ngFor is not used on the page again and messages is not used anywhere else either

Comment: And just to confirm, you still have `*ngFor="let msg of messages | async"` on the `ion-item` right? Also try the alternative I suggested also. Thanks

Comment: i think u said to remove async which i did. now added it back and it works just fine!